# 4GB RAM installed, Ubuntu shows 2.5GB

Tags: 14.04, ram, thinkpad

Lenovo ThinkPad E430, hardware is straight from the vendor, untouched.
There are 4GB RAM installed, one card.
Yesterday I discovered Ubuntu sees only 2.5GB.
BIOS detects 4GB RAM.

The system is 64bit Ubuntu 14.04.

I cannot quite firmly confirm that the 4GB worked sometime already, but since my last install I was actually a little upset about the system running a little slow. I really think 4GB worked in the past.

In BIOS setup I see no relevant setting, I already tried to disable Memory protection, it did not help. Also update-grub did not help.

```
> uname -a
Linux Crusader 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2531       2015        516        234         82        707
-/+ buffers/cache:       1225       1306
Swap:         9636          0       9636
```

lshw -c memory ( only a part ) :

```
*-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: a
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 4GiB
 *-bank:0
      description: DIMM [empty]
      physical id: 0
      slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
 *-bank:1
      description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
      product: HMT351S6EFR8C-PB
      vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
      physical id: 1
      serial: 0B67833D
      slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
      size: 4GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

Comment: please check the BIOS it should be like this [PHOTO](http://i.imgur.com/xXsuE9Z.png) and tell us back what is the amount of RAM you see in the BIOS

Comment: 4GB, as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your Laptop graphics card shares the RAM, it is reasonable to assume that the shortfall in RAM is being used / reserved by the graphics card and therefore unavailable.

It may be worth looking in to buying an additional 4GB RAM for you Laptop, as it has a spare slot.

Comment: But... 1.5GB? Is that not a little too much? That's almost half the RAM

Comment: Argentus: If the above is true, there should be a BIOS setting that allows you to bring the graphics memory usage back down to something more manageable.  Look for "display" in the BIOS. Also, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of the above answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: I did not, since it did not help me. In BIOS I found no such setting, under "display" there's only "Boot display device" - nothing interesting.